# mkdir: No such file or directory error

Tags: file, directory, mount, mkdir

I am trying to mount a file system using read only, but I am getting this error.

```
# cd Downloads
# ls
.localized
# mkdir /mnt/temp
mkdir: /mnt/temp: File exists
#  mount -o ro,loop -t Ext3 system1 /mnt/temp
mount: exec /Library/Filesystems/Ext3.fs/Contents/Resources/mount_Ext3 for /mnt/temp: No such file or directory`
```

Why isn't /mnt/temp showing up? I am in sudo

Comment: This looks like a mac.  Does MacOS X have native support for ext3 ? (i.e.: I'm suspecting that "No such file or directory" message refers more to `mount_Ext3` than `/mnt/temp`).